# What happen when Date type binding in Angular

Tags: angular

Why mydate(a type of Date).**setMonth(mydate.getMonth()+1)** not cause angular refresh mydate in view?

When I use, mydate = **new Date(mydate.setMonth(mydate.getMonth()+1));** view will get the correct value?

test.component.html

```
<label>{{currentDate | date:'MMM'}}</label>
<button (click)="nextMonth()">Next</button>
```

## Code 1

test.component.ts

```
currentDate: Date = new Date(); // get now
// others ...
nextMonth() {
  this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

## expected result

when I click "Next" button, the label will show month of next month.

## actual result

nothing changes when click "Next" button. When I console.log(this.currentDate) at the end of nextMonth method, it shows value of next month. but no changes in view.

## Code 2

test.component.ts

```
currentDate: Date = new Date(); // get now
// others ...
nextMonth() {
  this.currentDate = new Date(this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth() + 1));
}
```

## expected result & actual result

click "Next" button, label value changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
  locale = "en-us";
  currentMonth = new Date().toLocaleString(this.locale, {
      month: "long"
   });

 nextMonth() {
  this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
  this.currentMonth =  this.currentDate.toLocaleString(this.locale, {
  month: "long"
  });
}
```

then in your test.component.html use

```
<label>{{currentMonth}}</label>
<button (click)="nextMonth()">Next</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but my point is why just setMonth is not working? When currentDate call setMonth, the value of currentDate is **changed**, but why this change not shows in view? Why **new** Date works?